# xmlSignature or normal digital Signature?

Tags: xml-signature

Which is better? Signing a SAML document with xml Digital signature(xmlDsig) or normal digital signature. I want to know performance wise which is better and why is that better? As far i read, I felt both can be used. No big difference. Is there anything which I am missing out on Signatures?